# How can i solve the 'cannot find symbol' problem?

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol

If I compile this, I get 'cannot find symbol' errors with the setDefaultCloseOperation, setSize and setVisible. My problem is I don't understand why. and This is the part of myhomework. But I can't even start next part Because of this problem

```
//AdderSubtracterFrame.java
//This class displays a Frame which can add or subtract two numbers
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class AdderSubtracterProgram
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        AdderSubtracterFrame frame1 = new AdderSubtracterFrame("Adder and Subtracter");

        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setSize(400,100);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I add AdderSubtracterFrame code two classes are in the same project. This project is to make a calculator

```
//AdderSubtracterFrame.java
//This class displays a Frame which can add or subtract two numbers

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class AdderSubtracterFrame
{
    private JTextField num1TextField;
    private JTextField num2TextField;
    private JTextField resultTextField;

    private JButton clearButton;
    private JButton addButton;
    private JButton subtractButton;
    private JButton buttonPanel;

    //Constructor
    public AdderSubtracterFrame(String title)
    {
        //Set the title of the AdderSubtracterFrame by
        //using the superclass JFrame constructor
        super();

        //Set the JFrame to be a 2*2 Grid
        //Set a gap of 5pixels between each row and column.
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,5,5));

        //Create and instance of the components appearing in the 2*2 grid
        num1TextField = new JTextField("0",5);//Begin with 0
        num2TextField = new JTextField("0",5);//Begin with 0
        resultTextField = new JTextField((5));//Begin empty
        buttonPanel = getButtonPanel();

        //Add components to 2*2 Grid
        add(num1TextField);
        add(num2TextField);
        add(resultTextField);
        add(buttonPanel);
    }

    //Create and return a panel containing the buttons
    private JPanel getButtonPanel()
    {
        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
        myPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //Create an instance of each button
        addButton = new JButton("+");
        subtractButton = new JButton("-");
        clearButton = new JButton("CLEAR");

        //Add the 3button to myPanel
        myPanel.add(addButton);
        myPanel.add(subtractButton);
        myPanel.add(clearButton);

        return myPanel;

    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to show us the code for `AdderSubtracterFrame`. Does it extend `JFrame`?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is, that `AdderSubtracterFrame` does not extend `JFrame`. Therefore, you can't use `JFrame` functionality like `setVisible()`.

Declare your `AdderSubtracterFrame` like this to fix:

```
public class AdderSubtracterFrame extends JFrame {
```

Some other things I found:

- You call `super()` in your constructor but you don't pass the title. Change to `super(title)`.
- Don't use fixed sizes in your Java Swing GUI. Use layout managers (like you do) and call `pack()` on the frame to layout the frame according to the components inside the frame.
- The Java Swing GUI should be running on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: Omg I solve the problem. I can't believe it's this easy. thanks!

Comment: No worries. If this solved your problem, be sure to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

Make `AdderSubtracterFrame` extend `JFrame`, you only have to change this one line of code from

```java
public class AdderSubtracterFrame {
```

to

```java
public class AdderSubtracterFrame extends JFrame {
```